# NativeScript - how to delay routing until the sidedrawer has closed?

Tags: angular, nativescript

I'm writing an app with NativeScript 6.4.1 and Angular 8.

I've included the SideDrawer feature in my project.

https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/SideDrawer/getting-started 
So far it's working great.

One thing I noticed is that when I logout of the app, I logout through the SideDrawer and then route to the first page in the app. This transition from side drawer to the main page is not very smooth.

How can I wait until the side drawer has closed before routing or else make the transition smoother?

sample code:

```
export class LogoutService {

    constructor(private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions, private sideDrawerService: SideDrawerService) {}

    public logout(): void {
        appSettings.clear();
        this.sideDrawerService.closeDrawer();
        this.routerExtensions.navigate(['landing-page'], { clearHistory: true });
    }

}

export class SideDrawerService {

    constructor() {}

    public showSideDrawer() {
        const sideDrawer = app.getRootView() as RadSideDrawer;
        sideDrawer.showDrawer();
    }

    public closeDrawer() {
        const sideDrawer = app.getRootView() as RadSideDrawer;
        sideDrawer.closeDrawer();
    }

}
```

Edit: I can see in the documentation here that there are some events that are fired when https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-ui-api-reference/classes/radsidedrawer#drawerclosedevent

How do I listen for these events?

I tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
public closeDrawerAsync() {

    const sideDrawer = app.getRootView() as RadSideDrawer;

    sideDrawer.drawerClosedEvent //this does not seem to exist

}
```

Comment: You could wait for [drawerClosed](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-ui-api-reference/classes/radsidedrawer#drawerclosedevent) event before navigating away.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to integrate that with the router? If it works I will select as the answer.

Comment: You just have to add an event listener, before navigating away wait for event, straight forward.

Comment: Why did my question get a downvote? I will update it with more effort.

Comment: It's an event not attribute. Like any other events, loaded, tap etc., you add an event listener drawerClosed.

Comment: Can you provide an example because I don't know how to listen for the event?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211692/discussion-between-user1261710-and-manoj).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `drawerClosed` event

```
export class SideDrawerService {
    ...
    closeDrawer (callback?: () => void) {
       const sideDrawer = app.getRootView() as RadSideDrawer;
       if (callback) {
         callback = zonedCallback(callback);
         sideDrawer.once(RadSideDrawer.drawerClosedEvent, () => {
             callback();
         });
       }
       sideDrawer.closeDrawer();
    }
    ...
}
```

Now you can use it like,

```
public logout(): void {
    appSettings.clear();
    this.sideDrawerService.closeDrawer(()=> {
       this.routerExtensions.navigate(['landing-page'], { clearHistory: true });
    });
}
```